# Why is $\oint_p \frac{1}{z} dz=0$ in simply connected regions?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

According to Cauchy's Theorem, $\oint_p f(z) dz=0$ for any function $f(z)$ holomorphic on a simply connected region $U$ along any closed-path around any point $p$, provided point and path are within $U$.

When it comes to the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ and the problematic origin, I understand why $\oint_0 \frac{1}{z} dz=2 \pi i$, since evaluating $\log(z)$ along a loop equals to evaluating a difference of $2\pi$ in the argument of $z$.

However, if we calculate $\oint_p \frac{1}{z} dz$ in such a region $U$, won't we deal again with a loop of a logarithm and obtain again $2\pi i$? Why $0$?

Comment: It's because $U$ must be **simply connected** to apply Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: Analyticity is a _local_ property (whether $f$ is analytic at a given point may be decided by looking at an _arbitrarily small_ neighbourhood of that point), while having all contour integrals evaluate to $0$ is a global property.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to a region U that is actually simply connected (no holes in it). Am I missing something fundamental about the conditions of this domain?

Comment: Yes, Arthur, I know. I'm asking about any point p in U.

Comment: Hermès, my hypothesis is that U is a region where 1/z is holomorphic. In other words, simply connectedness of U is a given. Still I am confused because it's possible to evaluate the loop of the logarithm in that region and get a non-null result.

Comment: Holomorphic does not imply anything about the connectedness. The function $\frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} -\{0\}$ as well. So if you want to exclude those situations, you should edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Point taken mlk, thanks for highlighting. Hopefully the question is now more accurately expressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, Cauchy's theorem only applies to simply connected regions.
For example, if you choose $U=\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$, then $\frac1z$ is holomorphic in $U$,
but $U$ is not simply connected.

If $U$ is simply connected and does not contain $0$, then you cannot find a path that winds around $0$, so you dont have to worry about contour integrals whose path winds around $0$.

Note that the evaluation of the "loop of the logarithm" can only be nonzero, if you wind around $0$ (at least) once.

Comment: Notice I'm not choosing U=C-{0}. I'm choosing U as a simply connected region within C. It could be, for instance, a unit circle around z=5.

Comment: In the case of a unit circle around $z=5$ every path integral evaluates to $0$.

Comment: But, why? Won't you get another loop for log(z)?

Comment: because you dont loop around $0$, only around $5$. Try calculating it explicitly.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I see supinf, ufff. The angle doesn't "loop". It goes from z=6 up till z=5+i, then goes down till z=5-i, and up again to z=6. Indeed it doesn't describe an incremental loop of 2*pi increase. Wow, how thick. Thank you everybody for the immediate replies. First time I use this site, surely won't be the last one.